# Custom popup dialog with input field

Tags: android, android-dialog

How do I create popup input field for Android?
I need Xml and Java Code.

[image: Pop Up Input Field]

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a code factory

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try to use this custom popup dialog  code
main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPrompt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Prompt Dialog" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        </EditText>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Type Your Message : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

main.java

```
package cm.kikani.kalpesh;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;
    private Button button;
    private EditText result;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // components from main.xml
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrompt);
        result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextResult);

        // add button listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // get prompts.xml view
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // get user input and set it to result
                        // edit text
                        result.setText(userInput.getText());
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        }
                      });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom dialog class for your case.

your_custom_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Do you realy want to exit ?"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/blue"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_yes"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_no"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="No"
            android:textColor="@android:color/blue"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and you CustomDialog class must extend Dialog

```
public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog {

  public Activity activity;
  public Dialog dialog;
  public Button yes, no;

  public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.activity = a;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);

    yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
             activity.finish();
       } 
    });

    no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
             dismiss();
       } 
    });

  }

}
```

and you can call it like this

```
CustomDialogClass customDialog =new CustomDialogClass(activity);
customDialog .show();
```