# How to open a another activity (small screen) in the current activity without moving from current activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make an android application on this main_activity was launched and now when the user presses a button the camera_activity(this camera_activity launch an IP based camera from the remote location) should start in the current activity at the particular specific position or specific space in the current screen without disturbing current activity.

I used viewstub, it can only show images but it cannot open some activities

Comment: use fragments @suryateja

Comment: See [Android Activity as a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1979369/7666442)

Comment: Using Activity dialog blocks the current screen but I need both the activities are running without out affecting other @NileshRathod

Comment: fragments might help I don't know exactly how to call an activity in a fragment @AbhinavGupta

Answer (score 0):

> if you try to open second activity in main activity as a dialog or in small area then use custom dialog or fragments.
>
> basically fragment is used to open different view in same activity

please check below links

Custom Dialog:  [Custom Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861081/custom-popup-dialog-with-input-field)

Fragment:   [How to use Fragments](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/fragment)